# Impossible to launch Puppeteer with node-red on Raspberry

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, node-red

I have an issue when I try to launch puppeteer with my Raspberry using node-red. I am using the node-red-contrib-puppeteer-new library and this error code appears :

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-982053/chrome-linux/chrome: 16: Syntax error: ")" unexpected


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
```

What can I do to solve this issue ?
I have tried to modify the library without success

Best regards

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like a the owner has enabled issues on their fork of the base project so you can't easily ask them for help. I would suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73399554/edit) the question to show/explain how you have tried to modify the code. You may also do better on the Node-RED Forum where it will be easier for people to offer suggestions and try out different paths.

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo apt install chromium-browser chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
2. copy chromium-browser from /usr/bin/ to /.nodered/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-982053/chrome-linux
3. go to /.nodered/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-982053/chrome-linux
4. delete chrome
5. rename chromium-browser to chrome